# Why do I experience screen freeze?

Tags: kali-linux, freeze

I recently installed Kali-linux on my machine.

Sometimes it freezes randomly (which means I can't do anything on the graphical interface but can switch to TTYs), leaving the following message in my tty1:

```
[175005.476313] [drm:intel_set_cpu_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared fifo underrun on pipe A
[175005.476375][drm:ironlake_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU ppipe A FIFO underrun
```

Where does this problem come from and how can it be fixed?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I doubt the kali-linux tag is appropriate here. This seems to be an intel I915 driver bug, not at all related to Kali. I mentionned it in order to give a bit of context, but the tag is useless and even counter-productive if other people have the same problem with some other distro and can't find this question because it's tagged.

Comment: Why would the tag prevent people from finding this post?  It's entirely possible that this *is* a Kali problem.  Also, can you tell us some more about your hardware?

Comment: I use a ASUS X550L computer which has an intel core I3 processor, two graphic cards (you know, one is integrated in the motherboard and the other is a Nvidia 820M, running with bumblebee)

Comment: and it looks like [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95461), which is a "fixed" duplicate of [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79261)... so it would be an intel-video-driver bug :(

Answer (score 2):

I finally found an answer which can be useful if you have the same problem as mine:

As this warning message is a bug and cannot be fixed by myself, it was triggered by a configuration problem. monitor `/var/log/messages` to find the root cause (mine was a bad configuration of xkb, an easily-fixed error message) and then this i915 will never appear again after booting up (but it may appear at boot time, with no visible effect).

Answer (score 0):

just go to /sys/etc/default/grub

and modify  this line : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
into : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="-1"

save file and execute update-grub

this will fix your problem

Comment: I do not use Kali, but I never heard of `/sys/etc`.  You need to at least explain why it does fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same screen freeze issues with my linux and I fixed it this way:

Before you even log in. Enter tty (teletype) by pressing CTRL + ALT + F2, 3, 4, etc (whatever gets you to the tty terminal which is just a basic command line).
 Then login as root in tty. Update your system using "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade".

Then get your 3rd party Nvidia Drivers installed this will fix the repetitive freezes.

Wrong drivers are the reason for screen freezes.